# NOW() function local time retrieval for querying language design

Tags: mysql

Right now, I'm working on a querying language. We will have the command of 'today' which is really the equivalent of 'NOW()' in my MySQL.

I assume that today aka NOW() would get all records that have the user's local date of today rather than the servers? i.e. user is in hong kong and the date there is 21 Nov,2019 but the Server is in Canada along with the HQ and the date is 20 Nov, 2019 therefore if the user queries for all tickets created **today/now()** they would get all records created on the 21 Nov,2019 since thats their local time which would be none since most users in HQ are on 20 Nov, 2019.

Again, the alternative is to query on UTC, however for a client facing application the concept is far too difficult to explain and the data retrieved wouldn't make sense because it would neither be server time or local time.

Comment: Hi! With a similar problem I just did the inserts with the local operation date, so it was easier to consume on that country, you can save UTC times too for queries from another timezones

Comment: Thanks Alejandro!